# IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'getAppointment' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I m newbie to spring.I know my question is already answered here. but solution is not working for me.
So I m posting my question here. I m trying to handle multiple forms.I have 3 forms. 1st form working properly. second form it is showing jasper exception.

Category.java

```
public class Category {
    String category;
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

MyController.java

```
@Controller    
public class MyController {
    List<String> listOFDoc=new ArrayList<String>();


    @RequestMapping(value="/category", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView category(){

        return new ModelAndView("Category","command",new Category());

    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/getDoc",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getDoc(@ModelAttribute("command")Category c,Model model){

    //  model.addAttribute("list", c.getCategory());
model.addAttribute(new TypeOfDoc());
        String type=c.getCategory();
        System.out.println(type);
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("dentist")){
            listOFDoc.add("rj");
            listOFDoc.add("c");
        }
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("ortho")){
            listOFDoc.add("w");
            listOFDoc.add("x");
        }
        model.addAttribute("name", new Category());
        model.addAttribute("listOfDoc", listOFDoc);
        return new ModelAndView("List", "getAppointment", new Category());
    }

/*  @RequestMapping(value="/getDoc")
    public ModelAndView listOfDoc(){

        return new ModelAndView("List","getAppointment",new TypeOfDoc());

    }*/
    @RequestMapping(value="/showAppointment",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showAppo(@ModelAttribute("getAppointment")TypeOfDoc type,BindingResult results,ModelMap model){
        return "appointment";

    }

}
```

List.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" 
           uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>List OF doctors</title>
</head>
<%-- <body>
<c:forEach items="${listOfDoc}" var="doc">
<c:out value="${doc}"></c:out>
<br>
 </c:forEach> --%>

  <form:form method="POST" commandName="getAppointment" action="/Jmeter/appointment">
<form:select path="name">
<form:options items="${listOfDoc}"/>
</form:select>
<br>
</form:form>  
<input type="submit" value="submit">


</body>
</html>
```

Category.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
           uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Catogory</title>
</head>
<body>
<h:form method="POST" action="/Jmeter/getDoc.htm" commandName="command" ><!-- 
<select >
<option value="dentist"  label="dentist">
</option>
<option value="ortho"  label="ortho"></option>
</select> -->
<h:select path="category">

<h:option value="ortho" label="ortho"></h:option>
<h:option value="dentist" label="dentist"></h:option>
</h:select>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'getAppointment' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag.writeTagContent(SelectTag.java:194)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.page.List_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fselect_005f0(List_jsp.java:222)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.page.List_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(List_jsp.java:187)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.page.List_jsp._jspService(List_jsp.java:139)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: where is your bean for request map ->action="/Jmeter/appointment and for this corresponding method, do you have a model attached for commandName="getAppointment"

Answer (score 0):

You have a form

```
 <form:form method="POST" commandName="getAppointment" action="/Jmeter/appointment">
```

Where is your action mapping. , something like following. As the error says "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'getAppointment' available as request attribute", you must have this in your action class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/appointment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getAppointment(ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    map.addAttribute("getAppointment",
            yourAppointmentObject);
    //  do something
    return "Jmeter/";//some url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name
>   'getAppointment' available as request attribute

From the code you posted, it is apparent that the `getAppointment` object(TypeOfDoc) is not available when loading the `List.jsp` page. To resolve this issue, you can simply add a a `RequestMapping.GET` method in the controller class which returns that object.

For form processing, you got to have a `RequestMapping.GET` method in the controller to load/pre-populate the form and `RequestMapping.POST` method to handle the form submission.

For the form - `<form:form method="POST" commandName="getAppointment" action="/Jmeter/appointment">`

To prepopulate the form data,  you can use the method below in the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/appointment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAppoinymrny() {
        TypeOfDoc typeOfDoc = new TypeOfDoc();

        //your logic to add some data to typeOfDoc object so that it can be prepopulated in the form.

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("List", "getAppointment", typeOfDoc);
        return mav;
    }
```

Then when you submit the form, the below controller method will be called and you can do further processing..

```
@RequestMapping(value="/appointment",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showAppo(@ModelAttribute("getAppointment")TypeOfDoc type,BindingResult results,ModelMap model){

          //your logic
        return "appointmentSuccess";
    }
```